# Spree uninitialized constant Spree::UserSessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Am having a problem with Spree where I'm getting Spree uninitialized constant Spree::UserSessionsController when I try to go to the /admin page.
I am redirected to /login and it errors.

```
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-22 20:26:22 +1000
Processing by Spree::Admin::OrdersController#index as HTML
  Spree::Preference Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/backend_configuration/locale' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Completed 302 Found in 499ms (ActiveRecord: 14.4ms)


Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-22 20:26:22 +1000

ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant Spree::UserSessionsController:
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `rescue in controller'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:64:in `controller'
```

I am using spree 2.2. Gemfile is

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree', '2.2.0'
gem 'spree_bootstrap_frontend', github: '200Creative/spree_bootstrap_frontend', branch: '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_blogging_spree', github: 'stefansenk/spree-blogging-spree', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_editor', github: 'spree/spree_editor', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_print_invoice' , :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_print_invoice.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
```

I have double-checked spree.rb in the initializers folder. 
It has the standard `Spree.user_class = "Spree::User"`

All the routes and controllers I'm using are stock standard so not sure on what is causing this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

did you try to switch the order of spree and spree_auth_devise devise in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

Hey change sequence of spree gem in your Gemfile as follows.

Add spree gem top of other spree gem

```
gem 'spree', '2.2.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_bootstrap_frontend', github: '200Creative/spree_bootstrap_frontend', branch: '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_blogging_spree', github: 'stefansenk/spree-blogging-spree', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_editor', github: 'spree/spree_editor', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_print_invoice' , :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_print_invoice.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
```